# Django: How to open a small window on button click without changing url

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am using Django and I want to open a small forms window when I click on button 'Nouvelle Chirurgie' in template without changing the url and I don't know if I have to do it with js or no and how to do it, and after that how to save it in views. Actually, I'm this button take me to another page:

```
<a href="{% url 'register_visit' patients.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Nouvelle Chirurgie</a>
```

So, what should I do?

Comment: create something like a modal/container with the form with default `display: hidden` and `show` it upon click of element X. That's basic javascript handling

Comment: do you have an example like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap for this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           {{ form }}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).